# Extract rows in R dataframe which aligns with dummyvariable

Tags: r

I would like to create one vector of every MKT observation for when the dummy variable equals 1 and another vector when dummy equals 0.

This is how my dataframe looks:

[image]

Comment: `SP500.df$MKT[which(SP500.df$dummy == 0)]` and `SP500.df$MKT[which(SP500.df$dummy == 1)]`?

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution with `dplyr`:

```
df_new <- filter(SP500.df, dummy == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with base R as well.

```
## Case when dummy = 1
MKT_vector = SP500.df[SP500.df$dummy==1,]$MKT
```